# Pytest MonkeyPatch

Tags: python, mongodb, pytest

I am trying to patch `PyMongoClient` that has multiple nested commands that need to be patched.

One example would be instantiating the `PyMongoClient` (i.e. `client = PyMongoClient().db` then doing a command like `client.command('ping)`

Here is an example of what I have tried,

```
class DbMock:
    def command(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return True

class MockPyMongoClient:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        pass

    @property
    def db(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return DbMock()

mp.setattr('pymongo.MongoClient', lambda *args, **kwargs: MockPyMongoClient)
```

Main code c something like,

```
py_mongo_db = pyMongoClient(settings.MONGODB_HOST).db
try:
    py_mongo_db.command('ping')
except Exception:
    raise "MongoDB does not seem to be running, or is not healthy."
    )
print "MongoDB Healthy"
```

This creates the following error output:

```
AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'command'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
```

I have temporarily resolved it by, I wish for an explanation why the class replacement above doesn't work with a regular class but works with a MagicMock class.

It's not the class, I replaced it with an actual object and it works, but why doesn't it work just with the template of that class.. weird.. you have to pass an object.

```
mongomock = MagicMock
mongomock.db = DbMock()

mp.setattr('pymongo.MongoClient', lambda *args, **kwargs: mongomock)
```

This works.